# LINQ to create unique values of list of sub-objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of courses where the course object looks like this:

```
public class Course
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string CourseName { get; set; }
   public Teacher Teacher { get; set; } = new Teacher();
}
```

And for clarity, the teacher object looks like this:

```
public class Teacher
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to produce a list of unique teachers. I think I'm almost there but struggling to produce a List.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var teachers = from c in Courses // Courses is List<Course> with data in it
               group c by new { c.Teacher.Id, c.Teacher.Name }
               into uniqueTeachers
               select uniqueTeachers.ToList();
```

Looks like the issue is that I need to create a Teacher object in the group by line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: select just the name and use `Distinct`? Or you can implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you need the whole object (still need Distinct)

Comment: The teacher Ids should be unique so you can use Distinct on just the Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Traditional

The first `Select` gets a list of all teachers (non-unique).  We then `GroupBy` teacher ID and take the `First` instance of Teacher in each group.

```
var teachers = courses.Select (a => a.Teacher)
                      .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
                      .Select (g => g.First()).ToList();
```

No `IEqualityComparer` required.

### Extra credit

LINQ?  Why not [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Like, if you have a trillion courses, or something.

```
var teachers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Teacher>();
courses.AsParallel().ForAll(a => teachers.TryAdd(a.Teacher.ID, a.Teacher));
```

`TryAdd` will fail (but not throw an exception) if the ID is already in the list, so this will give you the uniqueness.  When the code is finished, you will have a dictionary with the ID and an object instance of each teacher.  This solution uses multiple threads if it will increase performance.

`IEqualityComparer` implementation not needed for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like BradleyDotNET user commented, you have to implement the `IEqualityComparar<T>` to take it done. For sample:

```
public class TeacherEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Teacher>
{    
  public override bool Equals(Teacher x, Teacher y)
  {
      return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode((Teacher obj)
  {
     return obj == null ? 0 : obj.Id;
  }
}
```

And try to use the `Distinct`:

```
var teacherComparer = new TeacherEqualityComparer();

var teachers = (from c in Courses
                select c.Teacher).Distinct(teacherComparer);
```

Comment: Won't work unless the object references are the same, you need an `IEqualityComparer` passed into `Distinct` most likely.